# How run python file in vsc terminal, if i have "permission denied"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, permission-denied

i try run python file in the terminal of visual studio code, with interpreter to run files python, i have one error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU1u1.png)  that i try fix with " chmod +x", i have WSL2 and also try with "sudo chmod +x" and nothing work.

i don't know how solve this.

Comment: what did you chmod?  `python`? (you really should paste the text here, even if you have to retype it)  or `main.py`?  what happens if you just plain `python` in wsl terminal, no vs code involved?

Comment: @Satan's Strike -Do you try to run the same file in a system terminal outside of VS Code? Have you tried to run files in other paths?